# Search Through HABTM Checkbox/List

Tags: list, cakephp, search, checkbox, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have this contact form which also relates to a few other tables with a HABTM relationship. They are displayed in the form either as a list or as checkboxes. What I want is to be able to search through them while still in the form to select those that are applicable to the contact I am adding with the form. I'm not sure how to do this- was thinking maybe Javascript?

An example of what I am talking about is like Facebook when you're searching through your friends list.

Below are the HABTM relationships for the Contact Model:

```
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Company' => array(
        'className' => 'Company',
        'joinTable' => 'companies_contacts',
        'foreignKey' => 'contact_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'company_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    ),
    'Event' => array(
        'className' => 'Event',
        'joinTable' => 'contacts_events',
        'foreignKey' => 'contact_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'event_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    ),
    'Screenoccupation' => array(
        'className' => 'Screenoccupation',
        'joinTable' => 'contacts_screenoccupations',
        'foreignKey' => 'contact_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'screenoccupation_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    ),
    'Tapearchive' => array(
        'className' => 'Tapearchive',
        'joinTable' => 'contacts_tapearchives',
        'foreignKey' => 'contact_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'tapearchive_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    ),
    'Relation' => array(
        'className' => 'Contact',
        'joinTable' => 'contacts_contacts',
        'foreignKey' => 'contact_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'related_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

Not sure what other codes I need to show you guys, so please do let me know what codes are needed and I will add them to this question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a jquery plugin to do the job for you.

It seems that [this one](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#filter) corresponds to your criteria. [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) is nice too.

Anyway, do a google search to see all the jquery plugin available, and see if one fits your need.

Comment: Thanks for that. The first one seems to suit my needs but I am having some trouble getting it to work. Can you please help me?
  
This is the HABTM selection that I have and I want it to use that jquery plugin.   
 <?php    
  echo $this->Form->input('Event', array('type'=>'select','multiple'=>'select'));
 ?>
Any ideas?

Comment: Simply create a standart multiselect in php, then call the javascript which will transform it.

Comment: Sorry ALS, Im not sure how to do that... This code: <?php echo $this->Form->input('Event', array('type'=>'select','multiple'=>'select')); ?> automatically creates a multiselect. Not sure how to do it otherwise...

Comment: Yes, that's what have to do. Then simply put $("select").multiselect().multiselectfilter(); in <script> tag, and don't forget to give the class to the select:

Comment: <?php echo $this->Form->input('Event', array('type'=>'select','multiple'=>'select','class'=>'select')); ?>

Comment: You'll have to call the javascript library for it to work of course.

Comment: It is working now BUT I dont know why it is appearing for every single select box. Eg. echo $this->Form->input('Contact.title', array('type'=>'select','options' => $title, 'default' => 'Mr.'));

Comment: ah. $("select").multiselect().multiselectfilter(); calls all select box. Put $(".select").multiselect().multiselectfilter(); with a dot, it will work only on the input with the select class.

Comment: Great!! It's working now! But it automatically selects an option by default. Any way to remove that default selection? I cant find anyting about it from the website. Also, the check all and uncheck all box is somehow missing for me. How do I add them to it? Cheers

Comment: The default comes from cake: you wrote:  echo $this->Form->input('Contact.title', array('type'=>'select','options' => $title, 'default' => 'Mr.')); just change default as you want.

Comment: This is the one which has a default value: echo $this->Form->input('Event',array('type'=>'select','multiple'=>'select','class'=>'multi'));

Comment: And dont worry about the check and uncheck box, I've just fixed it. Thanks

Comment: That's cakephp doing the default. Go read the docs to get exactly what you want.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you very much for your help! You've been great!! And sorry that I've been asking so many questions. I'm quite new to Cake and Jquery.